# According to the Nyquist criterion this system is stable but when I apply an impulse I get an unstable response, why?

Tags: transfer-function, stability, phase-margin, nyquist-plot

I have this open loop transfer function and I have to study the stability of the closed loop transfer function using the Nyquist criterion. What I got is that the characteristic equation 1+GH(s)=0 has two roots inside the Nyquist contour, the GH(s) transfer function has zero poles in the right hand plane and that the number of loops around -1 in the Nyquist Diagram is 2 so according to the Nyquist criterion, Z=N+P in which I get 2=2. So the system is stable, however the response I get to an impulse is this:

[image: Impulse response]

[image: GH(s)]

[image: Nyquist diagram]

Comment: The closed loop system is stable. But your plot is for open-loop, no?

Comment: To draw the nyquist plot I used the command nyquist(G) in matlab, where G is the open loop tf, but for the impulse I used the closed loop tf

Comment: Why do you say your time doman result indicates an unstable response? What happens if you extend the simulation to t > 25 s?

Comment: I tried it with t=50 s and it is still unstable

Comment: How did you build your closed loop function?

Comment: Since H(s)=1 the closed loop is G/(1+G)

Comment: I am rusty at this stuff, but looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_stability_criterion): *If the open-loop transfer function G(s) is stable, then the closed-loop system is unstable for any encirclement of the point −1.* - which seems to be your case

Comment: @EugeneSh. My theory is that if N=Z it just means that the open loop is stable but for the closed loop to be stable N needs to be equal to 0, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Review the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_stability_criterion), or your textbook.

The number of times the plot can loop around the critical point (-1 for open-loop plots, 0 for closed-loop) is equal to the number of *unstable* poles minus the number of *unstable* zeros.  This is because you are counting the number of poles minus the number of zeros that are encircled by traveling up the \$j\omega\$ axis, then around the entire right-half plane.

So your Nyquist plot is actually predicting an unstable system, which is exactly what you have.